# Update private ListFragment from parent activity

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, android-listfragment

I have a `FragmentActivity` which creates a `ListFragment`. Inside the `ListFragment` is a custom adapter. When I would try to make the adapter public, it wouldn't let me. So, I don't really have access to the adapter or I'm not sure how to get it. I add some data to the `listview` statically with a public arraylist of objects that I declare early in the lifecycle. However, other data I want to retrieve with `AsyncTask` from a Database. I get this data in the parent activity and I know right when it is finished fetching the data. So,
Can I update the `listView` within the `ListFragment` with access to the `arraylist`, but not access to the adapter? If so, can I do it from the activity or do I need to somehow call a method in `listFragment`? If I need to call a method in `listFragment`, how do I access that method from the activity? If this is not possible without access to the adapter, how do I get access to the adapter without the public keyword? Would it be better to move my `AsycTask` to my `ListFragmen`t?

I know it sounds like a lot, but I'm just wondering how to refresh the `listview` with those cicumstances. Help is greatly appreciated.

Call to method:

```
ListFragment fragment = (ListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragtag");
                fragment.updateData();
```

Method that refreshes:

```
public void updateData(){
    ((ArrayAdapter)this.getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

It is in my subclass of `ListFragment`, but not in any methods.

**Edit:**Now I get the following error:

`Error parsing data java.lang.ClassCastException: com.dynamic_internet_solutions.scsinfo.app.SpeakerListFragment$1SpeakersListAdapter cannot be cast to android.widget.ArrayAdapter`

**Edit - Solved: ** I did

```
ListFragment fragment = (ListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragtag");
BaseAdapter adapter = (BaseAdapter) fragment.getListAdapter();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after I set the tag of my fragment on initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have access to the ListAdapter of a ListFragment using the [getListAdapter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#getListAdapter%28%29) method. You can easily grab the list adapter and modify the data in it. I'm not sure why you are having trouble making your adapter public. Are you declaring it inline, or as a separate class? What is the error you are getting from the compiler?

As an aside, you might want to read my two articles on the [View Holder pattern](http://nick.codes/posts/view-holder-pattern-improved/) and making [reusable list adapters](http://nick.codes/posts/reusing-listadapters/) to make your ListAdapter more awesome.

Comment: It is in a class in the `onCreateView` method of the `ListFragment`. It says `public not allowed here.` That method works, but most people use `notifyDataSetChanged()` and it doesn't recognize `this.getListAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()`. It says "Cannot resolve".

Comment: ```notifyDataSetChanged()``` is not a member of [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html). You need to cast to the correct type you are subtyping in your ```onCreate()```. So if ```onCreate()``` does: ```new ArrayAdapter() { ... }``` then do ```((ArrayAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged()```

Alternatively, declare your ListAdapter class as ```public static class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter { ... } `` within the class instead of the method, or move it to another class file. You cannot make an anonymous inner class public.

Comment: So I can't use `notifyDataSetChanged()`? Then how do I refresh my `ListFragment`?

Comment: Reread the comment above. You have to cast to the subclass of ```ListAdapter``` that you are using since ```notifyDataSetChanges()``` is not part of the interface of ```ListAdapter```.

Comment: Thanks. Part one solved. I put that into a method in my `ListFragment`. Now how do I call that method from the parent `ListActivity`?

Comment: Grab the fragment using the FragmentManager. You will have to cast to your subclass of ListFragment to get access to your new method, or else you can just cast to a ListFragment, call getListAdapter() on that and then cast the result of that to your ListAdapter type.

Comment: I tried that and it shows a lot of the methods from the fragment, but not `updateData`. It is public, void, and not static. It is not in any other methods, just in the subclass of `ListFragment`. I added in method and call to method from activity in my question.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: The error says SpeakersListAdapter cannot be cast to android.widget.ArrayAdapter. This means SpeakersListAdapter is not subclassing ArrayAdapter. You must cast to the correct type. What type does SpeakersListAdapter extend?

Comment: It is extending `BaseAdapter`.

Comment: So cast to BaseAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter

Comment: After I did that I got a nullPointerException somewhere else in my code at runtime. I think you solved it. Thanks a lot.